# Custom Directive Error - Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

This is Code which I want to Import in Main NgModule of Application -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { KService } from './services/to.service';
import { CDirective} from './directives/to.directive';

@NgModule({
    exports: [CDirective],
    declarations: [CDirective],
    providers: [KService]
})

export class CTModule { }
```

I have Import **`CTModule`**  in Main Ngmodule of Application  i.e `AppModule` and I am getting 
Error -

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'CTModule' imported by the module
>   'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: in main.ts, did you still bootstrap AppModule?

Comment: @woodykiddy yes i bootstrap the AppModule. When I just comment that importing `CTModule ` in main module of app then everything works fine.